# If Abelian Group $G \cong G^3$, does it follow $G \cong G^2$?

Tags: abelian-groups, direct-sum, group-isomorphism

If an Abelian Group $G$ satisfies $G \cong G^{3}$, does it follow that $G \cong G^2$ ?

It seems elementary but I can't find it on a standard textbook exercise, and maybe simply because it's false.

sorry, Edit: I mistyped I mean $G\cong G^3$ implies $G \cong G^2$.

Before edited it was the converse, which is of course true (see Hagen von Eitzen's answer)

Comment: From the link given by Alex Youcis .. there's a reference to the other MO thread years ago:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3

there's also a negative answer to other categories including Banach Space and Stone Space.

Comment: The question was asked and answered [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10128/when-is-a-isomorphic-to-a3).

Answer (score 2):

You have $G\cong G^2=G\times G\cong G\times G^2=G^3$ (abelian or not, in any category with finite products)

Comment: ... but does $G\cong G^3$ imply $G\cong G^2$?

Comment: I think this answers your question: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/There_exist_abelian_groups_whose_isomorphism_classes_of_direct_powers_have_any_given_period

Comment: Ahh sorry, I mean if $G \cong G^3$ implies $G \cong G^2$

Comment: @AjatAdriansyah Did you see my link?

Comment: Ahh, I see, Thanks! That will do!

but I can't find the access to the paper.. 

Now I wonder, does anyone has another example in other categories aswell?